# How can I use python's argparse with a predefined argument string?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use the pythons argparse module to parse my cli parameter string. This works for the parameters a pass from terminal, but not with a given string.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Argparse Test script')
parser.add_argument("param", help='some parameter')

argString = 'someTestFile'
print(argString)

args = parser.parse_args(argString)
```

If I run this script I get this output:

```
~/someTestFile
usage: argparsetest.py [-h] param
argparsetest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: o m e T e s t F i l e
```

The `~/someTestFile` is somehow transformed in `o m e T e s t F i l e`. As already mentioned, it works if I pass the filename from the terminal.

I could imagine, that this has something to do with string encodings. Does someone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: you may want to take a look at the [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`parser.parse_args()` expects a sequence in the same form as `sys.argv[1:]`. If you treat a string like a sys.argv sequence, you get `['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'T', 'e', 's', 't', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e']`. 's' becomes the relevant argument, and then the rest of the string is unparseable.

Instead, you probably want to pass in `parser.parse_args(['someTestFile'])`

Answer (score 58):

Another option is to use [shlex.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split). It it especially very convenient if you have real CLI arguments string:

```
import shlex
argString = '-vvvv -c "yes" --foo bar --some_flag'
args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(argString))
```

Answer (score 7):

Just like the default `sys.argv` is a list, your arguments have to be a list as well.

```
args = parser.parse_args([argString])
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply `split` your command string :

```
args = parser.parse_args(argString.split())
```

A complete example to showcase :

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--dummy_opt', nargs='*', type=int, help='some ids')
    argString = "--dummy_opt 128 128"

    args = parser.parse_args(argString.split())

    print(args)
```

will output :

`Namespace(pic_resize=[128, 128])`