# How to make user-input parameters using if in python?

Tags: python

understandable versions of Question:

- How to detect and get strings inside of parenthesis?
- How to detect and get datatypes inside of parenthesis?
- How to detect and get strings inside of parenthesis using If?
- How to detect and get datatypes inside of parenthesis using if?

example:

```
x = input("send command(only allow 1 digits of character and only allow A,B<C<D<E<and F)")
if x == "$C A":
    print(x)
elif x == "$C B":
    print(x)
...
```

6 possibilities(if and elif statements)

tried: using rfind method, rpartition method translate method(translate from parenthesis to curly brackets), used format() method, used str() function

my code(with if statements):

```
def commandLine():
    c = input()
    if c = "$CR -f a"
        print("you made a file named a")
    elif c = "$CR -f A"
        print("you made a file named A")
...
```

possibilites: 15,000 or 7,000

lazy code:

```
def commandLine():
    c = input()
    if c = "$CR -f"
        f = input("filename: ")
        print(f)
```

possibilites with short code: Infinity(infinite characters can be typed in the f=input() variable)

Comment: You should learn about regular expressions.

Comment: Your code is hard to read with only 1 space for indentation. Please use the standard 4 spaces.

Comment: You can also use the `argparse` module to parse strings that look like command line arguments.

Comment: Your code has many syntax errors that you should fix before addressing the real question: = that should be ==, missing : at the end of if,

Comment: @Barmar argparse gets arguments from the commandline. im getting arguments from the c=input() variable

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878478/how-can-i-use-pythons-argparse-with-a-predefined-argument-string

Comment: i do not understand that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your input and make if/else statement with every parameter:

```
def commandLine():
    c = input()
    c = c.split(" ")
    if c[0] == "$CR":
      if c[1] == "-f":
        if c[2]:
          print("you made a file named {}".format(c[2]))
commandLine()
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were asking but it's what i understood. I hope it helps

Output:

```
$CR -f A
you made a file named A
```

Comment: i have a problem. so when i made a command that writes inside files, it only wrote the "hello," instead of "hello, world"

Comment: It this text is at the end of the command line you can use something like this: `" ".join(c[2:])` it will get all the text from the number of command that you put to the end of your command line

Comment: where do i put it?

Comment: in this example if you want a multi word name you should put it like this: `print("you made a file named {}".format(" ".join(c[2:])))` i can´t really tell you where to put it whitout looking at your code, but i think this example could help you